# ssh:// links in HTML with additional arguments

Tags: html, ssh

I’m trying to create a little static html start page with ssh links to all the servers I manage. I’m trying to create HTML links that will emulate the following:

ssh -t user@example.com "cd /home/user/; vim ruby.rb"

This works:

```
<a href=”ssh://user@example.com”>shell</a>
```

But I’m not sure how to pass the extra commands (to cd and edit the file via vim) to the href link.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no official URL scheme for ssh. Thus, this is dependent of the program you have set up to handle ssh:// urls. Alternatively, depending on your browser, you may define a custom url (let's say, "editrubyrb://user@example.com") which triggers a custom script launching the appropriate command

Comment: is there any reason behind not using `alias`(es) or at least functions in sh instead?

Comment: @chelmertz: I actually have bash aliases like you mentioned but I want to create a "pretty" start page with thumbnails of all the sites/servers and links to them via ssh (pop open a terminal and cd into specific directories).

Comment: imho I'd skip the browser for maintainability/speed, but I guess it makes for a fun project. Gl :)

Comment: Having commands execute from a URL is a security risk.

Comment: Having a command included in the URL is dangerous and is a security risk. Usually that part of the URL is reserved for directory names. Look at how [**`scp`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) handles SSH URLs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would create an alternative like ruby_ssh://, then create a custom URL handler in your browser, which varies by browser.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I'm going to try your approach and post my results if I'm successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to "emulate" it somewhat by fiddling with your .bash_profile. This way you can set a script to run when you login. 
Edit: of course, it would be done on your user accounts on *each server*, not on the client where you have the web browser.